# @State var doesn't update when changing the value outside the view

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I need to declare the checkBox array using "@State" if I want to use it inside the view using $checkBox and it works fine but when I want to update the toggles (1 or more elements of the array) in a function outside the view, the array is not updated. I tried to declare it using @Binding and @Published but without success. I saw many similar Q&A but I didn't find a solution for my case. This is my code:

```
struct CheckboxStyle: ToggleStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        return HStack {
            Image(systemName: configuration.isOn ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                .foregroundColor(configuration.isOn ? .green : .gray)
                .onTapGesture { configuration.isOn.toggle() }
            configuration.label
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var checkBox = Array(repeating: false, count: 14)
    let checkBoxName: [LocalizedStringKey] = ["checkPressure", "checkVisibility", "checkCloudCover", "checkAirTemp", "checkWaterTemp", "checkWindDir", "checkWindSpeed", "checkWindGust", "checkCurrentDir", "checkCurrentSpeed", "checkSwellDir", "checkWaveHeight", "checkWavePeriod", "checkTideHeight"]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Group {
                    ForEach(0..<7) { t in
                        Toggle(isOn: $checkBox[t], label: {
                            Text(checkBoxName[t]).font(.footnote).fontWeight(.light)
                        }).toggleStyle(CheckboxStyle()).padding(5)
                    }
                }
                Group {
                    ForEach(7..<14) { t in
                        Toggle(isOn: $checkBox[t], label: {
                            Text(checkBoxName[t]).font(.footnote).fontWeight(.light)
                        }).toggleStyle(CheckboxStyle()).padding(5)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thx for help

Comment: I don't see anything "outside the view" in the example -- can you illustrate what you're trying to do?

Comment: I just want to set the toggles in a function which is inside inside the ContentView and it seems that using an array of Bool doesn't work, I will have to define the toggles in the body view